# Can adverbs describe nouns

Tags: adverbs

Can adverbs describe nouns?

Down here are some examples I came up with(don't know if they are correct):

1

> > The party "tonight" will be great.

2

> > The project "since 2001" is a dead end project.

3

> > The room "upstairs" is a game room.

4

> > The concert "yesterday" was amazing.

5

> > The government's policies "last year" have been discussed by the public.

Comment: Those quoted words and phrases express temporal or locative attributes of the nouns they follow.

Comment: Such "attributes" do not inhere in the thing itself; they are contextual.

Comment: @Lucian Sava: What if there's not a full sentence  or the sentence is in a tense which is incompatible with the "adverb": "The concert yesterday..." or "I am speaking about the concert yesterday".  Yesterday I am speaking about the concert? You could resort to saying there's an implicit predicate, so that these are clausal constructs. Why not simply introduce the idea of contextual temporal and locative attributes?

Comment: If you're asking if adverbs can modify nouns - yes they can (though rarely). In your examples the words in quotes are not adverbs: "tonight" is a temporal pronoun modifying the noun "party"; "since 2001" is a preposition phrase modifying "project", "upstairs" is a preposition modifying "room"; "yesterday" is a temporal pronoun modifying "concert".

Comment: "temporal pronoun".    I simply refuse to drink the KoolAde. :)